# Releasing the cache of a WPF Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, imaging

I have a timer and on every tick I want to take an image file from memory and change the image that is being displayed in the `Image` with this piece of code

```
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Render,
            new Action(() =>
                           {
                               ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                               e.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);


                               BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                               bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
                               bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                               bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
                               bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
                               bitmapImage.EndInit();

                               CameraImageBox.BeginInit();
                               CameraImageBox.Source = bitmapImage;
                               CameraImageBox.EndInit();
                               bitmapImage = null;
                               ms.Flush();
                           }));
```

The Image control turns pitch black after a couple of dozen of images and the whole ui turns quite unresponsive. The memory use jumps to a whopping 1gig, I'm assuming the image controls render cache doesn't get released as `e.Image` is a static resource that gets redrawn every time.

Is there a better way to do this, like rendering the image in a `Rectangle` or manually releasing the cache?

Comment: I think you should dispose your memory stream, putting it in a using block for example, this is not clear from your code, where is the ms created?

Comment: ms is declared at the class level this is a event handlers something handled method every time a new image is handled this code executes that's why I thought it would be better to flush the ms and write something in there. Anyway the ms as far as my debugging went doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is my understanding that you are adding the image many multiple times to the `MemoryStream` at every single iteration.

this because your ms object exists from outside and is never disposed. If I am understanding what happens correctly:

```
// go to begin of stream
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// write your bitmap content into the stream 
e.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

...
...
...
// flush to write content to the stream
ms.Flush();
```

now in theory I understand you are overwriting the same bytes all the time, but why don't you dispose the `MemoryStream` with a using block inside your method and test the results instead of having it open as a global variable?